# file readallbytes against cloud drive throws cloud operation is invalid sometimes

Tags: c#, windows-10, cloud, icloud-drive

Using .net core 5.0.1 console app with c# and vs2019 enterprise on w10.  I'm writing an app that copies photos out of my icloud/iphoto drive using file.readallbytes and writes it to an external drive.  This is against unhydrated files that when accessed trigger the windows 'automatic file downloads'.

Normally this works fairly well except I get random errors of 'the cloud operation is invalid' or 'cloud operation failed' with a timeout.  If I restart the app sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  If I restart it enough eventually it will always get through the file and work.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is the code I am using.  I added some exception and retry logic to the code itself

```
                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            localfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fullsourcefilename);        // this should force the cloud provider to send it over.
                            success = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Failed with :" + ex1.Message);
                            retries--;
                        }
                    } while (!success && (retries > 0));

                    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(localfilebytes);     // this will throw an exception if not set which is fine.
```

This happens more often against very large files (100megs+) but sometimes happens with average or tiny files as well.

Why am I getting this error and how do I prevent it?  Is there another cloud api in windows I should be using to copy these files instead?

Comment: How good is your internet connection?

Comment: Xfinity 1gig.  Very high capacity.

Comment: My guess is that the service (icloud/iphoto) is flaky; that there is no way to prevent it; that all you can do is deal with it (i.e. retry). But, your post begs the question: what API are you using? Also, include some code, and the error codes and messages that you are getting.

Comment: Not using any apis from the cloud provider, just pointing at the cloud folder and copying the files out which forces the download.  If I try to drag/drop files out of the cloud folder it errors almost instantly, but this code at least makes it work most of the time.

Comment: I've found a lot more out since I asked this.  Basically ICloud for windows uses the OneDrive/Graph api.  I'm tracing down the EXACT details of how this happens and will be putting together a visio on the architecture when I find it which I'll share here.